# How to change url in address bar through java

Tags: java, jsp, url, address-bar

How can I change the url in the address bar through java code in browser(not through javascript or any front end languages)?

I have the url in the address bar like " http://www.abcde.com/home?abc=def&ghi=jkl " but I need to change that url through java code like " http://www.abcde.com/home ". I'm using jsp's for view.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use session variables (or something along those lines) instead of request strings...?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc By clicking that url (in some other site) will redirect to my webpage, and in my webpage i'm trying to remove those request params.

Comment: Have a look to [UrlRewrite](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#configuration) library. I'm not sure it will fit your situation, but you can add a rule to rewrite your url e.g. `<from>^/world.jsp?country=([a-z]+)&amp;city=([a-z]+)$</from>` `<to>/world/$1/$2</to>`

Comment: What is your goal by doing this? Is it just that you want to get rid of the request parameters?

Comment: @Jeyp Yes , request params coming from url is some sort of sesitive information.

Comment: Even if you manage to remove it via wrapping some objects....wouldn't this information still be passed over the network (via packets)?  It would be only a bit more secure.

Comment: What do you mean by "through java code in browser" Are you talking about an applet or a separate java-program that integrates with the browser?
Or are you talking about server-side?

Comment: @TejeshYadav - Then I'd say you use https as protocol and transfer your sensitive information via POST, not GET. Then the information passed gets wrapped in the request body, instead of being passed over in the URL. And the whole request is secured by using the https protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL with the request parameters comes from a page on which you have no control (or if it is a link) you can do the following :

- use a servlet on that URL
- if it finds request parameters in the query strings, it gets them and store them in session, then redirects to itself with no query string
- if there is no query string, get the parameter from session, remove them from the session to avoid to reuse them *by mistake* and process the query

If the parameters exists in query string, because of a form using GET method, simply change the method to POST to pass the parameters in the request body instead of the query string.